# Improve performance when importing data to MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, xml, django, json

I'm using Django to build a website with a MySQL (MyISAM) backend.

The database data is imported from a number of XML files that an external script process and output as a JSON-file. Whenever a new JSON file differ from the old one, I need to wipe the old MySQL-db and recreate it using manage.py loaddata, (at least that's the easy way to do it, I guess I could check the differences between the JSON files and apply those to the database, but I haven't figured out a good solution for this (I'm neither a very good coder nor a web developer)).

Anyway, the JSON file is around 10 Mb, and ends up being about 21,000 rows of SQL (It's not expected to grow significantly). There are 7 tables, and they all look something like this:

```
class Subnetwork(models.Model):
   SubNetwork = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   NetworkElement = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   subNetworkId = models.IntegerField()
   longName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   shortName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   suffix = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

It takes up to a minute (sometimes only 30 seconds) to import it into MySQL. I don't know if this is to be expected from a file of this size? What can I do (if anything) to improve perfomance?

For what it's worth, here's some profiler output https://gist.github.com/1287847

Comment: Make sure DEBUG=False in settings.py.  I had a 300mb file to import that would routinely run for an hour or so and fail.  I changed DEBUG and it started running in 30 min and completing.  Something about the ORM using more memory to cache queries when DEBUG=True...

Comment: That shaved off a couple of seconds off the load time. A good start I guess, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by exporting the processed XML-files to csv instead of json, and then used a separate script that called mysqlimport to do the importing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions, same decent than others, but here is a workaround to keep your system's "downtime" minimal, without needing to write a db synchronize mechanism (which would probably be a better solution in most times).:

- Create a custom `settings_build.py` file, with `from settings import *` that chooses a random name for a new db (probably with the date in the db name), creates it by calling mysqladmin, and update the name into [`DATABASES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases).
- Create a [custom django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) (let's call it `builddb`) by either cloning the `loaddata` command or calling it, and on successful result, it should write the db name to a `dbname` text file with one line and executes a shell command that reloads your django ([apache](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode#Restarting_Apache_Processes)/[gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/faq.html#how-do-i-reload-my-application-in-gunicorn)/?) server.
- Modify your `settings.py` to load the database name from the text file.

And now run your build process like this:

```
./manage.py builddb --settings=settings_build
```

Comment: That's an option I've thought about (that is, creating a new database for every import), but unfortunately I don't have full access to the MySQL-server and can only use the database I've been assigned.

Comment: If you can get access to one more db, you can still use this method by alternating the two dbs.

Comment: True. I might use this as a last resort if I don't come up with a way to actually cut down on the time.